# Need help explaining how this prime number program works

Tags: java

I have this code here that asks a user to enter a number then calls the `isPrime` method to calculate if the number is prime or not. It then prints out to the screen the result. I did a lot of trial and error to get this code to work, but I don't really understand all the way why this program works. For instance if I enter 9, the code would give me back a remainder, which should return true, which should make 9 a prime number, but it's not and the program works, saying that 9 is not a prime number. Just wondering why it works.

```
package homework_chap5;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework_Chap5 {

            //Pg 313 #7

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        int num = s.nextInt();

            if(isPrime(num)) {

                System.out.println("Number is prime");

            } else {

                System.out.println("Number is not prime");
            }   

    }         

         public static boolean isPrime(int num)
    {


        for(int i = 2; i <= num/2; i++)
        {
            if (num%i==0)
            {
             return false;
            }

        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For instance if I enter 9, the code would give me back a remainder, which should return true

No, for `num==9` and `i==2`, `num%i==0` will be `false`, but the loop will proceed to check for `i==3` whether `num%i==0`. This time the condition will be true and the `isPrime` method with return `false`.

Only after the loop ends, at which point we know that `num` is not divisible by any of the values of `i` tested, the method will conclude that `num` is a prime number and return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, `a number is prime if it is divisible by only 1 and itself`. Also rather than checking divisibility of the number `num` by all the numbers between 1 and num, it is sufficient to check for divisibility by numbers between 1 and `num/2` because no number greater than the mid value of the number  `num` perfectly divides the number. So go from 2 till `num/2` and see if any number divides the number num i.e. num % i == 0 where i in range [2, num/2]. If any such i exists then the number is not prime. If for no i in the range [2, num/2] num%i == 0 then num is prime.

However, the code can be optimized by checking for divisibility of num by all the numbers in range `[2, sqrt(num)]`instead of `[2,num/2]`. You can check the efficiency for your self.